# Debian 9 /.bashrc variable showing file not found instead of being ignored

Tags: bash, debian

I have the following little script that will tell me what packages are needing the server to reboot. I would like to put this in the ~/.bashrc so I see it when I log in.

```
#shows which packages require the server to be rebooted
package=$(cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs)
if [ ! -f /var/run/reboot-required ]
then
echo "No packages require reboot. Have a nice day :)"
else
echo "*** Hello $USER, you must reboot your machine because of the following 
package(s): $package ***"
echo
fi
```

However when I log in, since this server right now doesn't have any packages that require the server to reboot I am seeing this:

```
cat: /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs: No such file or directory
No packages require reboot. Have a nice day :)
```

How can I get it just to show the message stating there are no packages that require reboot? Other than this little issue all is working correctly. It does show me files that require reboot.

Server is Debian 9.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move `package=$(cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs)` to your `else` branch?

Comment: Thank you @Cyrus. That worked. I'm so used to declaring any variables at the top of my code.

Comment: Indenting your code would make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @Cyrus for helping me. I tried his suggestion of moving the the variable into my else statement and that worked.

Code Before:

```
#shows which packages require the server to be rebooted
package=$(cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs)
if [ ! -f /var/run/reboot-required ]
then
echo "No packages require reboot. Have a nice day :)"
else
echo "*** Hello $USER, you must reboot your machine because of the following 
package(s): $package ***"
echo
fi
```

Code After Cyrus's suggestion that worked:

```
#shows which packages require the server to be rebooted
echo
if [ ! -f /var/run/reboot-required ]
then
echo "No packages require reboot. Have a nice day :)"
else
package=$(cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs)
echo "[*** Hello $USER, your must reboot your machine because of the following 
package(s): $package ***]"
echo
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The "No such file or directory" is an error message from the `cat` command. Just redirect stderr:

```
package=$(cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs 2>/dev/null)
```

Or, a slight variant on the suggestion in Cyrus's comment, test whether it exists before reading it:

```
if [ -e /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs ] ; then
    package=$(cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs 2>/dev/null)
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

But that runs a slight risk of a race condition, if the file happens to be removed while this code is running.

You seem to be assuming that `/var/run/reboot-required` exists if and only if `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs` exists. That may well be true, but at least be aware that it's an assumption.